# Linux on Marvell 88SE9230. How to get stats?

Tags: linux, smartctl, smart

I use Marvell 88SE9230 controller on my home Linux server. HP does have utility to setup raid and get some stats. But I'm wondering how to get any status from a Linux system. Quick googling shows only Linux drivers for accessing array itself on previous versions of kernel, but I want to know SMART status of drives.

Smartctl doesn't work:

```
root@iris:~# smartctl -a -d marvell -T verypermissive /dev/sda
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-96-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: Unknown error

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Thu Jan 27 19:11:54 2022 MSK
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
                  Checking to be sure by trying SMART RETURN STATUS command.
SMART support is: Unknown - Try option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
Read SMART Data failed: Success

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: Success
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

Read SMART Error Log failed: Success

Read SMART Self-test Log failed: Success

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

How can I get at least some stats from controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm, same lack of support here (exact same output as OP when attempting to GET SMART stats off a device through Marvel chipset).

```
:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9230 PCIe SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11)

Linux fermmy 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 16:43:35 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

  *-sata
       description: SATA controller
       product: 88SE9230 PCIe SATA 6Gb/s Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 11
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: sata pm msi pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:43 ioport:d050(size=8) ioport:d040(size=4) ioport:d030(size=8) ioport:d020(size=4) ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fc710000-fc7107ff memory:fc700000-fc70ffff
```

There are no viable options directly from Marvell that I see; https://www.marvell.com/support/downloads.html

--
***BUT LOOK HERE!***

https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/downloads/ds539334-marvell-storage-utility-for-linux-for-linux

In theory ... this should work right? Let's try.

I was on Ubuntu, and didn't feel like making this work on CentOS derivative ; luckily someone did all the heavy lifting already: CREDIT: https://github.com/stegm/marvell_msu_docker

Some minor things were stale and I fixed/improved in this fork:
https://github.com/fermulator/marvell_msu_docker

Follow the README instructions :) - and then we can see:

```
    ~/projects/marvell_msu_docker$ docker-compose run --rm msu cli
SG driver version 3.5.36.
CLI Version: 4.1.10.42   RaidAPI Version: 2.3.10.1088
Welcome to RAID Command Line Interface.

> info -o vd

Virtual Disk Information
-------------------------
id:                  0
name:                RAID1_SSD
status:              functional
Stripe size:         64
RAID mode:           RAID1
Cache mode:          Not Support
size:                488306 M
BGA status:          not running
Block ids:           4 0 
# of PDs:            2
PD RAID setup:       3 2 
Running OS:          no

Total # of VD:       1
```

BONUS: even the web UI actually works!

[image: marvel MSU on Linux web UI]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link(s) for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page(s) change. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/409873)